# How to copy with the mouse from tmux in VS Code to the OSX clipboard

Tags: macos, ssh, mouse, tmux, clipboard

I connect to a remote server with VS Code through ssh, using https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/ssh, so I'm not using iTerm.

I open a Terminal window in VS code. Using the mouse to copy text to the macOS clipboard works nicely here: I can select text with the mouse in this terminal window, copy it with <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and paste it in any other macOS application with <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>.

However, I need to run tmux on the remote server. Once I start tmux, I can select text with the mouse (it briefly flashes yellow) but I cannot paste it in other applications, which means that it has **not** been copied to OSX clipboard. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In VS Code you'll need to set the `terminal.integrated.macOptionClickForcesSelection` option to `true`.  This will allow you to select text in the terminal as long as you <kbd>option</kbd>+click when selecting text.

NOTE: Selecting text with the mouse in this manner doesn't honour the `tmux` panels unfortunately so typically I find myself needing to zoom / maximize the panel prior to selecting (at least if selecting multiple lines of text) which isn't ideal.